# Makefile if conditional function inside foreach

Tags: if-statement, foreach, makefile, emscripten

I am trying to run in makefile something like this, and I am a newbie in writing makefiles.

```
EXECUTABLES = emcc em++ emcmake emconfigure emmake

K := $(foreach exec,$(EXECUTABLES),\
        $(if $(shell which $(exec)), \
        @echo "Emsdk binaries are already added to path", \
        $(if [! -d "${HOME}/.wasm/emsdk"]), \
        @echo "Emsdk is not installed consider running bash install_requirements first",\
        @source "${HOME}/.wasm/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh"))
```

But it throws error saying something like this `` insufficient number of arguments (1) to function `if'.  Stop. `` . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this part of your assignment is intended to mean:

```
    $(if [! -d "${HOME}/.wasm/emsdk"]), \
```

but it's definitely incorrect syntax.  You have closed the if function with only one argument, where it needs at least two.

Maybe you really wanted to use `$(shell ...)` here?  But I don't understand what this would do; make's if-function doesn't look at exit codes.

Comment: It is indented to check whether a folder at the path does not exist

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.  I'm not talking about indentation.  I'm saying that the reason you see this error is because `$(if [! -d "${HOME}/.wasm/emsdk"])` is not a valid make `if` function construct.  Make's `if` function has the form `$(if <cond>,<true>[,<false>])` and your version doesn't have the `,<true>` part.

Comment: Also just to mention, `[! -d "${HOME}/.wasm/emsdk"]` is also not a valid shell test: you have to have whitespace after the opening `[` _and_ before the closing `]`: `[ ! -d "${HOME}/.wasm/emsdk" ]`

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist your comments helped to better understand the `if ` function in makefile and resolve this.